# How to return the nearest DNS IP based upon requesting client's IP?

Tags: linux, networking, dns, ip

To achieve a faster internet experience, one aspect that can be optimized is to ensure a client is making use of a nearby DNS, rather than something on the opposite side of the world that might require too many network hops, too long to reach.
Does anybody know of any Linux software that, given a requesting client's IP, the software figures out and returns the IP of the nearest or somehow fastest DNS that the client should use?

Comment: do you mean a "smart" configuration of possible internal DNS servers into /etc/resolv.conf, or an enhanced resolver for external domains?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I refers to the second one, I need a "smart" resolver for the external domain.

Comment: I think you'd have to modify the client's resolver library; there may not be much you can do if there's only one authoritative NS for a domain, though. perhaps a caching nameserver would help?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, check out [Namebench](https://code.google.com/p/namebench).

> Try out namebench. It hunts down the fastest DNS servers available for
>   your computer to use. namebench runs a fair and thorough benchmark
>   using your web browser history, tcpdump output, or standardized
>   datasets in order to provide an individualized recommendation.
>   namebench is completely free and does not modify your system in any
>   way. This project began as a 20% project at Google.
>
> namebench runs on Mac OS X, Windows, and UNIX, and is available with a
>   graphical user interface as well as a command-line interface.